# Как получить url стороннего сайта №2 после редиректа из ссылки на сайте №1

Tags: vkontakte-api, curl, dom, iframe, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте!

Есть сайт, на нем ссылка на авторизацию в вк [https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=ххх&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=%D1%85%D1%85%D1%85&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html)

после перехода по ссылке редиректит на [https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=ххх](https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=%D1%85%D1%85%D1%85)

как получить эту редиректную ссылку кодом(чтобы взять access_token и автоматически писать его в бд), php, js не важно..

curl пробовал (не получилось)

post message + iframe пробовал (chrome выкидывает X-Frame-Options: sameorigin)
(типа допускаются только окна с одним адресом)

в расширении хром получилось взять ссылку но тут возникает проблема с установкой, (в ручную устанавливать его пользователю из за токена это бред..) нужно тогда автоматически, когда токен сдох подтягивать расширение -> узнавать токен(записать) -> удалить расширение т.к. оно дело сделало..
(сопутствующий вопрос тогда = как по тихому установить расширение кодом, и потом по тихому удалить(по тихому = это для удобства!!))

подсказывали Html 5 SharedWorker но там похоже тоже домен вкладок должен быть один

events -> storage (вобще молчу там тоже прослушка вкладок только одного домена)

cors не пробовал т.к. разбираюсь в нем слабовато

вобщем конкретные траблы с этим токеном.. подскажите пожалуйста, может у кого есть идеи !? спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Есть небольшой пример для вас. Этот код, после нажатия на ссылку переведет на сайт `ВК`, где пользователь подтвердит доступ и тогда произойдет редирект по указаному адресу, где вы уже `GETом` получите этот самый код.

```php
    $client_id = xxxxxx; // id приложения
    $client_secret = xxxxxx; // секретный ключ
    $redirect_uri = 'http://site.ru/vk.php'; // Адрес сайта

    $vk = 'http://oauth.vk.com/authorize';

    $params = array(
        'client_id'     => $client_id,
        'redirect_uri'  => $redirect_uri,
        'response_type' => 'code'
    );

    echo $link = '<p><a href="'.$vk.'?'.urldecode(http_build_query($params)).'">Войти через ВК</a></p>';
```

Нам придет такой ответ: `http://site.ru/vk.php/?code=xxxxx`

Далее нам надо запросить этот токен вот такой функцией(параметры из кода выше, переменная `code` пришла с ответом на сервер):

```php
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $params = array(
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
        'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
    );

    $token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);
}
```

В итоге мы получим такой ответ в переменную `$token`:

```
{"access_token":"xxxxxx","expires_in":xxxx,"user_id":1}
```

Там же ее декодим и делаем уже все что нужно.

Больше в отличной документации тут: vk.com/dev/access_token

Comment: Спасибо ! Но такой вариант я использовал, это серверная авторизация и у нее обратный редирект это сайт приложения а не вконтакте, а мне нужна короткая авторизация implicit flow - responsetype=token, так вот при ней обратный редирект идет не на сайт приложения а остается на одной из страниц vk.com =  https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html, и в этом то и проблема как раз что с помощью isset()  тут уже не подхватишь т.к. домен другой

Comment: Вот тут в документации даже пример есть, когда implicit flow переводит на другой домен: https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user . Либо я никак не пойму вашу проблему.

Comment: Все правильно он переводит на домен вк oauth.vk.com/blank.html цитирую :
Во всех остальных случаях (мобильное, десктопное приложение) необходимо использовать redirect_uri по умолчанию: https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html 

И мне как раз и нужен этот вариант потому что метод которй мне нужен с другим токеном не работает (проверял !!)

Comment: Тогда вам нужен JS и... >Если Вы разрабатываете веб-приложение и хотите работать с API из Javascript, в redirect_uri необходимо указать адрес страницы на Вашем сайте. В целях безопасности, этот адрес также должен быть указан в настройках Вашего приложения (поля «Адрес сайта», «Базовый домен» и «Доверенный Redirect URI»)

Comment: метод не работает с токеном полученном через редирект на какую либо страницу сайта приложения а работает только через полученный с редиректом на oauth.vk.com/blank.html, я конечно могу указать в настройках blank.html но смысл то не в этом, мне по сути токен нужно вытащить из url на чужом домене с api я работаю через php

Comment: Если вы работаете через PHP, то скорее всего с сервера. Тогда implicit flow не ваш вариант как мне кажется, тогда уже проще пройти полный цикл. В документации сказано, что такой токен не валиден для запросов с сервера.

Comment: в том то и суть что я использую метод wall.post а там такое Этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя, полученным в Standalone-приложении через Implicit Flow, или с использованием окна подтверждения.

Comment: Его можно и через вышеуказанную схему в ответе. Можно и так, и так. Я получал когда-то общий токен для wall.post в Standalone и с сервера парсил и отправлял новости в группу.

Comment: токен полученный через code у меня выдал ошибку, вы уверены что именно сейчас через code работает !?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил ошибку. Приложение, созданное в ВК должно быть "Веб-Сайт", тогда токен получается. Если пройти по ссылке в примере ВК https://vk.com/dev/authcode_flow_user и указать редирект на свой сайт, задав необходимые права, то работает.